# UIScrollView cannot display image either in Portrait or Landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a VC with orientation in Landscape in storyboard

I have added an `UIIScrollView` in it , say, make it: (w)1000, 500 (h) in the VC.

What I wanted to do:

1) Scrolling the image (with high resolution like 1334 x 750) inside `ScrollView` 
2) view the image in `ScrollView` in landscape mode

```
To make ScrollView to display the image, I have to do it in `viewDidAppear` 

but here the Problems:

1) The Width and height of the `ScrollView` is gone
 
2) label on top gone.

3) The `ScrollView` Size become small something like 200 x 150 and start from the Top corner like (0,0) 


What I need to do to make `scrollview` size like before 1000 x 500?


--- Update -- 



class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myUIScrollView: UIScrollView!  

    var imgView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        //-- force to landscape mode:

        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")


        self.myUIScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
        self.myUIScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        self.myUIScrollView.delegate = self


        imgView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "MyPhoto.png"))


    }


 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

     self.myUIScrollView.contentSize = imgView.bounds.size

     self.myUIScrollView.addSubview(imgView)

     view.addSubview(myUIScollView)
}


    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

            return true
     }


    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imgView
    }
```

Comment: If you are using Xcode assets and you have an image collection named my-image, you have to to use UIImage(name: "my-image").

Comment: Not working. Say I created image set in Xcasset call : Photo1 and my put MyPhoto.png ,MyPhoto1.png , MyPhoto2.png ,..in it. I followed your method. I use UIImage(named: "Photo1"), it wont work.

Comment: You have to create an image set for each image and the spaces are for three sizes like image1.png, image1@2x.png and image1@3x.png and then you can init your UIImage with name "image1".

Comment: Displaying image is ok now after I changed the code in viewDidAppear. The problem now is that the Scrollview become so small in my updated code. it stick to the top corner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var image: UIImage!{
    get{
        return myImageView.image!
    }set{
        myImageView.image = newValue
        myImageView.sizeToFit()
        myScrollView.contentSize = myImageView.frame.size
    }
}

var myImageView = UIImageView()

@IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!{
    didSet{
        myScrollView.delegate = self
        myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 10.0
        myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
        myScrollView.addSubview(myImageView)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    image = UIImage(named: "one")
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return myImageView
}
}
```